# SQL query where in X values and not Y values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Probably a softball question as I'm pretty bad with SQL. Basically, I have a table that has multiple rows per user. I'm trying to build a query to select users if they have certain values from that table also not select those users that have certain values.

```
###User Table
(ID)
###Device Table
(ID, UserID, Type)
```

So basically, I would like to only query users that have at least 1 row in the device table that has Type 1, 2, or 3.  But not select users that have 4, 5, or 6 EVEN if they have 1, 2, or 3.

It has to work with SQL Server and Compact.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1 from devices d where d.userid = u.id and d.type in (1, 2, 3)) and
      not exists (select 1 from devices d where d.userid = u.id and d.type in (4, 5, 6));
```

Or, you can do this directly on `devices`:

```
select userid
from devices
group by userid
having sum(case when type in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when type in (4, 5, 6) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from user
where ID not in(select userid from device where type in(4,5,6))